# How to determine the root cause of a performance spike during a heavy load on DB2?

Tags: db2, performance, db2-luw, load-testing, performance-testing

I am testing the performance of an application that links to a DB2 database engine at the back end.

Looking at the transaction timer logs, I see that on the 37'th minute into the test run, transactions take a very high time to process. This lasts for maybe a few seconds and then the run proceeds at acceptable speed.

I've done three test runs (restoring the data to initial test data, clearing up everything = basically, ensuring each run has the same starting position) and they all experience the same phenomenon: at the 37'th minute, a performance spike:
[image]

My current lead is that I notice, on the second run it's more visible, that every 37-ish minutes, there's a "minispike".

I think what's going on is the DB2 is doing some regular maintenance every 37 minutes, and the first maintenance job is a bit harder, as the machine hasn't cached a required program or...?

I am wondering what advice can I get to investigate this further? Debugging my own application did not show any reason to hang as it does there.

Info: 
DB: DB2 10.5.0.7
OS: SLES 12 0
App: Precompiled to bind to DB2 in 64-bit mode

Comment: Assuming that this is the database, you'll need to look at what is actually happening *in* the database before during and after that timeframe to determine what is going on.  That said, it may not be the database.  It could also be network, system, SAN, etc, and the database also a victim.

Comment: Anything in db2diag.log for that time?

Answer (score 2):

This *could* be one of the autonomic maintenance processes, e.g. automatic collection of table statistics, although the 37 minute interval looks a bit suspect.

You can start with looking at `db2diag.log` at around the time of the spike -- most auto maintenance tasks would be logged there.

For a quick look at what thread might be busy, run

```
db2pd -edus interval=<seconds> -repeat
```

around the time of the spike, choosing the interval appropriate for the spike width.

Another useful tool is the system stored procedure `MONREPORT.DBSUMMARY(<seconds>)`, which will print the summary of various wait times over the specified period -- run it before, during, and after the spike to compare the numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I will try these when I am back on this task and update accordingly